# Removing unwanted key/value pair in php array?

Tags: php, mysql

```
$data = array("0"=>"1","id"=>"1","1"=>"mani","name"=>"mani","2"=>"ssss","lname"=>"ssss");
```

above is my output but i want an array like below format. Please help me.

Correct Output:

```
$data = array ("id"=>"1","name"=>"mani","lname"=>"ssss");
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you want to remove a value from an array you can use [`unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

Comment: Don't use `mysqli_fetch_array()` as it returns both a numerical and aossciative array. Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead.

Comment: Look like you have queried as fetch_array. Try using fetch_assoc.

Comment: @JohnConde please suggest me using through php code.

Comment: I already told you what to do. Also, read my first comment. This is not a free coding service.

Comment: `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this, use is [is_numeric](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to check number or string.

```
$data = array("0"=>"1","id"=>"1","1"=>"mani","name"=>"mani","2"=>"ssss","lname"=>"ssss");

foreach ($data as $key => $val)
{
    if(!is_numeric($key))
    {
        $new_array[$key] = $val;
    }
}  

print_r($new_array);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => mani
    [lname] => ssss
)
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/676169)**

Comment: As OP tagged this question with mysql OP's array looks like it is returned from a query and just changing the fetching mode would be the correct solution.

Answer (score 1):

> The Code-Snippet below contains Self-Explanatory Comments. It might be of help:

```
<?php

    // SEEMS LIKE YOU WANT TO REMOVE ITEMS WITH NUMERIC INDEXES...

    $data       = array(    "0"    => "1",
                            "id"   => "1",
                            "1"    => "mani",
                            "name" => "mani",
                            "2"    => "ssss",
                            "lname"=> "ssss"
                        );

    // SO WE CREATE 2 VARIABLES TO HOLD THE RANGE OF INTEGERS
    // TO BE USED TO GENERATE A RANGE OF ARRAY OF NUMBERS
    $startNum   = 0;        //<==   START-NUMBER FOR OUR RANGE FUNCTION
    $endNum     = 10;       //<==   END-NUMBER FOR OUR RANGE FUNCTION

    // GENERATE THE RANGE AND ASSIGN IT TO A VARIABLE
    $arrNum     = range($startNum, $endNum);

    // CREATE A NEW ARRAY TO HOLD THE WANTED ARRAY ITEMS
    $newData    = array();

    // LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY... CHECK WITH EACH ITERATION
    // IF THE KEY IS NUMERIC... (COMPARING IT WITH OUR RANGE-GENERATED ARRAY)
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
        if(!array_key_exists($key, $arrNum)){
            // IF THE KEY IS NOT SOMEHOW PSEUDO-NUMERIC,
            // PUSH IT TO THE ARRAY OF WANTED ITEMS... $newData
            $newData[$key]  = $value;
        }
    }

    // TRY DUMPING THE NEWLY CREATED ARRAY:
    var_dump($newData);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'mani' (length=4)
      'lname' => string 'ssss' (length=4)
```

> Or even concisely, you may walk the Array like so:

```
<?php

    $data       = array(    
                        "0"     => "1",
                        "id"    => "1",
                        "1"     => "mani",
                        "name"  => "mani",
                        "2"     => "ssss",
                        "lname" => "ssss"
                        );

    array_walk($data, function($value, $index) use(&$data) {
        if(is_numeric($index)){
            unset($data[$index]);
        }
    });

    var_dump($data);
    // YIELDS::
    array (size=3)
      'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'name' => string 'mani' (length=4)
      'lname' => string 'ssss' (length=4)
```

Comment: As OP tagged this question with mysql OP's array looks like it is returned from a query and just changing the fetching mode would be the correct solution.

Comment: @Rizier123 Absolutely.... That's actually the right way to go.... overlooked that though; but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array("0"=>"1","id"=>"1","1"=>"mani","name"=>"mani","2"=>"ssss","lname"=>"ssss");
$new_data = array();
foreach($data as $k => $v)
if(strlen($k)>1) $new_data[$k] = $v;

print_r($new_data);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little confused as to what exactly you're looking for. You give examples of output, but they look like code. If you want your output to look like code you're going to need to be clearer.

Looking at tutorials and documentation will do you alot of good in the long run. PHP.net is a great resource and the array documentation should help you out alot with this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array.php